# float within fixme target doesn't get color

Tags: floats, fixme

I don't know if this is possible, but I would like the abillity to put floats inside a `fixme` target, and then get the caption and contents of the float to be colored.

Here's my current example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=color}
\begin{document}
\fxerror*{this is wrong right now}{ text and $math$ plays nice
        \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{cc}
                        1&1\\1&1
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Hello there}
                \label{tab:somelabel}
        \end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image: The yeld of the MWE[1]]

It would be really cool to have the table and caption also colored in

Comment: It is probably never a good idea to place a float inside a macro and think it applies to the float. In its very nature a float is removed from the normal processing of the document, and reinserted when the page is assembled. What are you even trying to do here?

Comment: @daleif The color of the `text and $math$ plays nice` should also apply to the table and caption, That way people could see that the table was wrong from my fixme note (I don't care if it floats away, but if it had the same color as the text below it it would be clear that it was attatched to an error somewhere)

Comment: Since you're using memoir, we can actually do something about this, but we need to hook into `\fxerror*`, which I have not figured out how to do automatically just yet. But in my test, placing `\setfloatadjustment{table}{\color{red}}` explictly before `\begin{table}` inside the second arg to `\fxerror*` does color the table, and only this table.

Comment: The only reason for `table` is to declare the content as _not_ part of the current document flow but rather a moveable block that can be inserted at a place convenient for page breaking, so latex goes to some effort to ensure that the line width, font and colour are _not_ inherited. Just use a`tabular` directly if you want it to be inside the note.

Comment: @daleif I think there is a color from `fixme` called `fxtarget` that should be used on the targts in the text XD

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would like it to float, It's just that it should get the color from `fixme` such that collaborators can see that it needs changing. If I just had a `tabular` environment then I would need to remove the `fixme` and add a `table` environment when done, I would much rather be able to write `final` in the package options and just have the color turn back to normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `memoir` where are some possibilities we can use. We just need to dig up the right `fixme` macros to mess with (you might want to send a feature request to the `fixme` maintainer)

This seems to do what you are after

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
draft,
%final
]{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=color}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% only add it when final is not active
\@ifpackagewith{fixme}{final}{}{
  \patchcmd\@fxtargetlayout@draft{\begingroup}{%
    \begingroup%
    \setfloatadjustment{table}{\color{fxtarget}}
  }{\typeout{patch ok}}{\typeout{patch not working}}
  % this let is the annoying part, \@fxtargetlayout is activated 
  % using \let, meaning any later readjustments to 
  % \@fxtargetlayout@draft is not applited unlet we let it again
  \let\@fxtargetlayout\@fxtargetlayout@draft%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\fxerror*{this is wrong right now}{ text and $math$ plays nice
          \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{cc}
                        1&1\\1&1
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Hello there}
                \label{tab:somelabel}
        \end{table}
}


        \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{cc}
                        1&1\\1&1
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{A non fx error table}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen  You can also swing by 1530.221 if you're in MatKant sometime.

Comment: I would love to, but I'm currently an exchange student in Finland ;-)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen hehe